# Nomad UI shows fewer client/server nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, nomad

I'm running Nomad in AWS and I'm seeing fewer nodes in the Nomad UI than exist in the cluster. On AWS if there are 6 Nomad client nodes, the Nomad UI would only show 4 or 5. Similarly for Nomad servers.

Any idea why this might be happening?